# Network Analyst and street intersection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

Im working on project for calculating pedestrian and bike accessibility to public services.For pedestrian I already could produce Isochrone maps ( by applying the street slops) now I want to calculate and produce the service area (Isochrone) for bikes by applying both street slope and also street intersections.I mean applying street intersection as travel cost. I don't know how to do it.